# Error:Dividing by Zero (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, types, int

I am trying to make a program to ascertain what positions of a 8x8 chess board is safe to put a knight on if 2 queens are placed on the board.

The input of the function is `[0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0]`, so it is called like `knightPlace [0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0]`. All nonzeros are queens.

As you can see, the 3rd and 6th element of the list is 6 and 4, which results in queens being at the 3rd column and 6th row and 6th column and 4th row (assuming you start at 0,0 at the bottom left corner of the chess board).

My col and row check were filtering fine but my diagCheck brought a new error msg:

```
knightPlace[0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0]
*** Exception: divide by zero
```

Can someone please help me out? It should never be 0 because the diagCheck solves for the slope of a queen and another coord, making it false and therefore not added if the slope is == 1 or -1

Here is the code I use:

```
knightPlace n = makeboard n 
    where 
    makeboard n = [(i + 1,j + 1) | i<-[0..(length n -1 )], j<-[0..(length n - 1)], colrowcheck n i j]
    -- col and row check, if the condition ==FALSE it doesnt get added 
    colrowcheck n i j = and [(n!!(i) == 0) && n!!(k) /=(j+1)| k<-[0..(length n -1 )], not(diagcheck n i j k) ] 

    -- diagcheck
    diagcheck n i j k = ((j+1) - n!!(k)) `div` ((i+ 1) - k)  == -1 || ((j+1) - n!!(k)) `div` ((i+1) - k)  == 1
```

Comment: In order to use `div` as an infix function you must enclose it in backticks: `(j - n!!(k)) \`div\` (i - k)`

Comment: Wow okay I fixed that, but now its saying Im dividing by zero, I will change the question accordingly

Comment: You should make a new question instead of changing this one, so you don't invalidate the answer.

Answer (score 3):

(This answers the original question posted by the OP, before the edits.)

This looks wrong:

```
(j - n!!(k)) div (i - k)  == -1 || (j - n!!(k)) div (i - k)  == 1
```

Try adding a few backticks:

```
(j - n!!(k)) `div` (i - k)  == -1 || (j - n!!(k)) `div` (i - k)  == 1
```

Off topic: the above can also be rewritten as

```
((j - n!!k) `div` (i - k)) `elem` [-1,1]
```

Back on topic: to improve the GHC error messages, try adding a few type annotations for your functions. E.g.

```
knightPlace :: Int -> [(Int,Int)]
knightPlace n = makeboard n 
    where 
    makeboard n = [(i + 1,j + 1) | i<-[0..(length n -1 )], j<-[0..(length n - 1)], colrowcheck n i j]

    colrowcheck :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> Bool
    colrowcheck n i j = and [(n!!(i) == 0) && n!!(k) /=(j+1)| k<-[0..(length n -1 )], diagcheck n i j k ] 

    -- diagcheck
    diagcheck :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
    diagcheck n i j k = (j - n!!(k)) `div` (i - k)  == -1 || (j - n!!(k)) `div` (i - k)  == 1
```

Adding these type annotations allows GHC to detect type errors early. In your original code, the snippet

```
(j - n!!(k)) div (i-j) == -1
```

computes `j - n!!k` and then treats it as a function accepting two arguments, namely `div` and `i-j`. GHC infers a function type for `j - n!!k` and moves on. There are no type errors in `diagcheck`, but they will pop out as soon as you try to call `diagcheck` with lists of integers instead of a list of functions.

Comment: adding your type annotations makes every function fail, Im not sure why but I think most of them are because :
Couldn't match expected type `[Int]' with actual type `Int'
Couldn't match expected type `[a0]' with actual type `Int'

what is type [a0]

Comment: @REALLYANGRYSTUDENT I changed the annotations to what I guess are the correct ones. Feel free to experiment with them and use whatever matches your intuition: if you know a parameter is a list of ints, use `[Int]` for that, and so on.